# is there a way to use external dependencies with @testable annotation in unit tests in the IOS module in a Flutter plugin?

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter, unit-testing, plugins

I'm writing an IOS module in a Flutter plugin and I would like to write unit tests for it.

The IOS module has one dependency and this is declared into the `.podspec` file. I need to use the classes from this dependency to write the unit tests. The most of classes from this dependency are set up as `final` therefore I need to use the `@testable` annotation to high access to these classes.

I have tried using the `@testable` annotation therefore I received this exception:

```
Module 'x' was not compiled for testing
```

Trying to solve this issue I checked out:

- `Enable Testability` as Yes for the targets.